# Order BY CASE with UNION ALL expression TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to order by a text column alphabetically, but keeping nulls last.

I can accomplish this fine in most cases by `ORDER BY CASE WHEN myCol is null then 0 else 1 end DESC, myCol ASC`

But I'm running into a particular scenario where MSSQL does not like it -- When I am trying to order a UNION of results.

Consider this:

```
   Select 'b' as word
UNION ALL 
select null as word
UNION ALL 
select 'a' as word 
ORDER BY word ASC
```

This is valid syntax, but doesn't order the nulls properly.

If I apply the logic below I will get an error:

```
Select 'b' as word
UNION ALL 
select null as word
UNION ALL 
select 'a' as word
order by case when word is null then 0 else 1 end desc, word asc
```

I am aware that if if I use a subquery or query a table/view(as shown below), it would work, but I have weird reasons why I am avoiding it and I am also curious

```
select * from (
Select 'b' as word
UNION ALL 
select null as word
UNION ALL 
select 'a' as word
  ) a

order by case when word is null then 0 else 1 end desc, word asc
```

What could I add to the `ORDER BY` clause after the union (in the middle example) to make it work?

[Here's a SQLfiddle if you'd like to see for yourself](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/073338/11)

Comment: Short answer is no, you cant, you need to do the sub select, or a CTE

Comment: Weird. I just tried it in SQL Server 2012 and 2019 and this bug exists in both versions. Strange that such an obvious error persists for such a long time in the DBMS.

Comment: @Brad But I don't wanna...

Comment: CTEs are your friend. Embrace them.

Comment: @pmbAustin As i said, I'm looking to avoid a CTE or subquery in this specific instance and just do it in-line. It does not appear that there is a way though...

Comment: I cannot imagine why you feel 'avoiding a CTE' is any sort of requirement. They're extremely useful. And in this case, they solve your problem.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you want to avoid using a subquery or CTE as well. Is it just something you're trying to figure out? Or is there some business purpose behind it? Genuinely curious.

Comment: @BJones I don't know what the OP's requirement is but one example would be if you creating an indexed view.

Comment: @AlanBurstein, I see... Well in that case one might just order results from the view using the logic, right?

Comment: @BJones Yeah there was kind of a technica/business reason for it. This query was being built as a string dynamically (adding UNIONS in each iteration of a loop). I worked around it and ended up wrapping it in a subquery like I mentioned in my OP and people suggested, but was hoping for an answer. I guess there isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting...

Here's how I'd do it.

```
Select 'b' as word,  0 AS ItsNull
UNION ALL 
select null as word, 1 AS ItsNull
UNION ALL 
select 'a' as word, 0 AS ItsNull
order by ItsNull, word ASC;
```

Returns:

```
word ItsNull
---- -----------
a    0
b    0
NULL 1
```

Comment: This is how I would do it as well. +1

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you  have to avoid `CTE` and `subquery`, you can add a dummy sort column for the purpose and do the sorting `in-line` as:

```
 --Follows a pseudo code to add a dummy column
Select word, CASE WHEN word is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as sortcol
from Words
UNION ALL 
select  word, CASE WHEN word is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
from Words
UNION ALL 
select  word, CASE WHEN word is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
from Words
order by sortcol desc, word asc
```